# functions in object literal javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object-literal

i'm a newbie starting to learn java-script..

```js
const textchanger = function () {
let text = "text that has been changed now"
const picktext = function () {
    let element = document.querySelector("h1")
    element.textContent = text

    return {
        callfun: function () {
            picktext();
            console.log(text);

        }

    }

}
}

textchanger.fun()
```

```html
 <h1> Getting started </h1>
```

i'm trying to change the text inside

```
<h1>Getting started</h1>
```

but getting the error..

> TypeError: textchanger.callfun is not a function
> at Object.

Comment: If you use a snippet then also use the _"Tidy"_ option to properly format/indent your code.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. `.textcontent` should be `.textContent`

Comment: @Andreas `picktext` isn't being called or returned so it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Andy Missed that extra "layer"... :/

Comment: return {
            callfun: function () {
                picktext();
                console.log(text);

            }

Comment: here the picktext is called right ?

Comment: OP can you go through that code and explain what you think it's meant to do? At the moment you have a function you're not calling, an inner function that you're not returning/or calling, and an object returned from that inner function that contains _another_ function that tries to call the inner function for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're experimenting with [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) but to do that you need to *return* the inner function from the function you initially call. You can then assign that returned function to a variable, and then call that.

Here's an example that shows how this works. (The `setTimeout` is there to show how the same function can be called again with different text, and get a different result.)

```js
// Accept an element, and return a new function
// that accepts some text. `element` will be returned
// along with the inner function so it can be used
function textChanger(element) {
  return function (text) {
    element.textContent = text;
  }
}

// Cache the element
const element = document.querySelector('h1');

// Call `textChanger` with the element as its
// argument, and assign the returned function to
// a variable
const changeText = textChanger(element);    

// Call that function with some text
changeText('First text!');

// Call the same function with some different text
setTimeout(changeText, 2000, 'Second text!');
```

```html
<h1>Getting started</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextChanger is the function not a plain variable so below code works:

```
textchanger().callfun()
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'callfun')
    at <anonymous>

Answer (score 0):

textchanger is a function, but It doesn't return any thing!
I think you mean this:

```js
const textchanger = function () {
  let text = "text that has been changed now";
  const picktext = function () {
    let element = document.querySelector("h1");
    element.textContent = text;

    return {
      callfun: function () {
        picktext();
        console.log(text);

      }
    }

  }
  return picktext(); // <==== put this line
}

textchanger().callfun();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const textchanger = function () {
let text = "text that has been changed now";
const picktext = function () {
let element = document.querySelector("h1");
element.textContent = text;
  return {
    callfun: function () {
    picktext();
    console.log(text);
   },
  };
};
  return picktext(); ==>return picktext() function 
 };

textchanger(); ==> by calling this the text will be changed
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).